# Use of moment js (_d and _i)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment js in the project. I would like to set the date entered in the datetimpicker. I get the value of the input in the following format.

```
saltValue: "08052019"
value: "08.05.2019"
__proto__
: constructor
: ƒ Object() hasOwnProperty
: ƒ hasOwnProperty() isPrototypeOf
: ƒ isPrototypeOf() propertyIsEnumerable
: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable() toLocaleString
: ƒ toLocaleString() toString
: ƒ toString() valueOf
: ƒ valueOf() __defineGetter__
```

and I'm converting with the following function.

```
let dateValue = getDateValue(inputValue);
  static getDateValue(value) {
    return Moment.utc(value);
  }
  şu kısım da ise set etmetedir.

  let newDate = dateValue._d;
  this.setState({
    initialDate: newDate,
    displayDate: getFirstDayOfMonth(newDate),
    selectedDate: newDate,
   });
```

However, the dateValue variable has an old date in the _d parameter and a new date in the _i parameter. I have to use to set my new date. But the _d and _i property variables are not the same. The _d parameters are used in different places of the project. So I have to get my new date in _d format. How can I do this?

```
_i property;
   "08052019"
value:"08.05.2019"
__proto__
:constructor
:ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty
:ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf
:ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable
:ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString
:ƒ toLocaleString()toString
:ƒ toString()valueOf
:ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__
:ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__
:ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__
:ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__
:ƒ __lookupSetter__()get __proto__
:ƒ __proto__()set __proto__
:ƒ __proto__()_isAMomentObject
:true_isUTC
:true_isValid
:true

_d property;
__proto__
:constructor
:ƒ Date() getDate
:ƒ getDate() getDay
:ƒ getDay() getFullYear
:ƒ getFullYear() getHours
:ƒ getHours() getMilliseconds
:ƒ getMilliseconds() getMinutes
:ƒ getMinutes() getMonth
:ƒ getMonth() getSeconds
:ƒ getSeconds()getTime
:ƒ getTime()getTimezoneOffset
:ƒ getTimezoneOffset()getUTCDate
:ƒ getUTCDate()getUTCDay
:ƒ getUTCDay()getUTCFullYear
:ƒ getUTCFullYear()getUTCHours
:ƒ getUTCHours()getUTCMilliseconds
:ƒ getUTCMilliseconds()getUTCMinutes
:ƒ getUTCMinutes()getUTCMonth
:ƒ getUTCMonth()getUTCSeconds
:ƒ getUTCSeconds()getYear
:ƒ getYear()setDate
:ƒ setDate()setFullYear
:ƒ setFullYear()setHours
:ƒ setHours()setMilliseconds
:ƒ setMilliseconds()setMinutes
:ƒ setMinutes()setMonth
:ƒ setMonth()setSeconds
:ƒ setSeconds()setTime
:ƒ setTime()setUTCDate
:ƒ setUTCDate()setUTCFullYear
:ƒ setUTCFullYear()setUTCHours
:ƒ setUTCHours() setUTCMilliseconds
:ƒ setUTCMilliseconds()setUTCMinutes
:ƒ setUTCMinutes()setUTCMonth
:ƒ setUTCMonth()setUTCSeconds
:ƒ setUTCSeconds() setYear
:ƒ setYear() toDateString
:ƒ toDateString() toGMTString
:ƒ toUTCString() toISOString
:ƒ toISOString() toJSON
:ƒ ()toLocaleDateString
:ƒ toLocaleDateString()toLocaleString
:ƒ toLocaleString()toLocaleTimeString
:ƒ toLocaleTimeString()toString
:ƒ toString()toTimeString
:ƒ toTimeString()toUTCString
:ƒ toUTCString()valueOf
:ƒ valueOf()Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive)
:ƒ [Symbol.toPrimitive]()
```

Comment: `_d` and `_i` are [internal properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) and should not be used. _To print out the value of a Moment, use `.format()`, `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`_

Comment: How about just using `<input type="date">` and `elm.valueAsDate`? it will show the format in clients own prefered format. And you will get the date in ISO standard format back, if u just do `elm.value`